# Formula to identify days in current financial year between two periods

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am seeking some excel formula help to identify the number of days in a set period ie. that fall in the current financial year. I've seen some other posts about this topic and tried all the formulas there (I'm not a sophisticated user so may have got things wrong!). This one works to a point, but not if the AU start date falls outside the current financial year

```
=MIN(AV4,DATE(IF(MONTH(AV4)<=6,YEAR(AU4),YEAR(AU4)+1),6,30))-AU4+1
```

Really appreciate any assistance you can provide to help me smarten up my formula :) As you will see at the below link to the table example, the plans with start days prior to the current financial year throw an incorrect answer.

The question I am trying to answer is: how many days within the start and end date of the plan sit within the current financial year.

Table example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try this:*

[image]

**Formula in cell V2:**

```
=IF(CHOOSE(MONTH(T2),7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6)<6,DATEDIF(S2,T2,"d"),"Not Current FY")
```

---

**:Edited:**

*Caveat*

- Solution shown in this part address the comments below by the OP.
- *OP wants number of days between Start and End date after been checked
  whether both belongs to current FY or not.*

[image]

Formula in cell:

U2: `=IF(AND(S2>=$Y$1,S2<=$Z$1),S2,DATE(2022,7,1))`

V2: `=IF(AND(T2>=$Y$1,T2<=$Z$1),T2,DATE(2023,6,30))`

W2: `=IF(AND(YEAR($U2)=2022,YEAR($V2)=2023),DATEDIF($U2,$V2,"d"),"No FY")`

**N.B.**

- Adjust cell references as well Months falls in FY according to
  current region.
- For above used data the financial year starts from JULY.
- Yo may hide Helper columns.
- Date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Rajesh. I'm not sure if that is showing what I need??? Take for example line 3 in the table you kindly placed above. Assuming the formula picks up on the current FY which is July 2022 to June 2023 there are 12 months in the current FY in that plan start and end date. The plan starts in March 22 and ends in Feb 2024, so it should show 365 days within the current FY sit within the life of the plan - yes???? For line 2, there is only a month and a half within that plan date that sits in the current FY, not 365 days. Really appreicate the help, I may not have explained well enough!

Comment: @KellieJean ,, thanks for responding me,,, in fact the KEY issue as U have written was Current FY so that,,, I've suggested the formula,,, please edit the post & share some sample data along with expected OUTPUTs,, will help me to fix it ☺

Comment: Thanks @RajeshSinha. Really appreciate the support. I am trying to identify how many days within a set period fall within the current financial year. So for example if the start date of the plan is 1/2/21 and the end date is 1/2/23 this plan goes across both the 21/22 and 22/23 financial years. I need to see the number of days within those dates that are in the 22/23 financial year. - so just the number of days from 1/7/22 to 30/6/23 (in this example case the number of days between 1/7/22 and 1/2/23). Does that help?

Comment: @KellieJean ,, okay give me some time I'll try to fix it soon ☺

Comment: @KellieJean ,, please check the edited part of my post I'm sure that addresses the issue,, expecting feedback. ☺

Comment: thanks so much Rajesh! I'm just away on holidays with the kids right now but will get back into this late this coming week when I get home and let you know how I go :)

Comment: Hi again Rajesh. I think we are almost there! Just a couple of times its not working.

In your table above at line 6 you can see that the result is NoFY but in fact there are three months in the current financial year in that one ..... so the formula is working for some dates but not others. As per attached.

I'm really so very thankful that you are working on this for me, I really do appreciate it. We are almost there! Thanks so much!!

Comment: I think it has something to do with the 2023 year expressed in the forumla! I note that all the errors relate to the dates which don't end in 2023 :)

Comment: I managed to fix one of the problems - woo hoo!  =IF(AND(YEAR(DG4)=2022, OR(YEAR(DH4)=2023,2022)),DATEDIF(DG4,DH4,"d"),"No FY")

Comment: Just one last problem to fix:  when the dates are all outside of the financial year 3/06/2021 3/06/2022 1/07/2022 30/06/2023 364

Comment: @KellieJean ,,, let me first address the core issue,,, IN LINE 6 start and end date are doesn't belong to current FY,,, check the criteria  in cells Y1 & Z1,,, as below U have fixed it,,,  logically WRONG ,, because the dates must be fall within CURRENT FY year's Start & End Dates,,, like for your region I've motioned in cells Y1 & Z1,,,, so one has to works accordingly.  In special circumstances you need to adjust VALUES in formula as U did with OR ,,,, ALWAYS REMMBER RULEs are RULE,,, for FY,, doesn't allows experiments otherwise spoil results. ☺

Comment: @KellieJean ,, if U believe that I've solved the issue then U may UP VOTE as well Accept the post as ANSWER ,,,, [Just hit this,,](https://superuser.com/tour) ☺

Comment: thanks @RajeshSinha - it got me close enough - thank so much for all your help :)

Comment: Glad to help you @KellieJean ,,,, please either put a caption ,,,, just above the screen shot you have loaded,,, that is posted by you ,,, or post it as a NEW Answer ,,, along with the formula U have used,,,, you will get Up vote ,,, and keep asking ☺☺

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh's forumla worked except for the one in W2 which I changed to

`=IF(AND(YEAR(DG4)=2022, OR(YEAR(DH4)=2023,2022)),DATEDIF(DG4,DH4,"d"),"No FY")`

So in full:

```
U2: =IF(AND(S2>=$Y$1,S2<=$Z$1),S2,DATE(2022,7,1))

V2: =IF(AND(T2>=$Y$1,T2<=$Z$1),T2,DATE(2023,6,30))

W2: =IF(AND(YEAR(DG4)=2022, OR(YEAR(DH4)=2023,2022)),DATEDIF(DG4,DH4,"d"),"No FY")
```

I did not resolve the last part but was able to move forward without it: when the dates are all outside of the financial year